# Why does adding a label to my XIB, and then linking it to a property in my .h file, cause a coding-compliant exception?

Tags: ios, xcode, exception, interface-builder, iboutlet

I have an xib.  I add a label to it and link it to a property, like so.

[image: Image of the label showing up from File's Owner properties, which matches the property to which it is hooked up, in code, for that class.]

The connection is established in the usual CTRL + drag manner where you hold down CTRL, click on the label, and drag it over to the .h file to be prompted for the property name and press  "Connect".

This causes a crash with the message below, when an app is run with the built nib.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key whyWontXCodeBehave.'.

- Leaving the connection causes the crash.
- The crash does not occur if I remove the connection between the property and the IBOutlet, but now I have no reference to that control.

Any suspicions?  I'm sure you, as I, have hooked up such controls/properties in this way before with no problem.

**NOTE**.  A resource bundle is what holds the nib.  That resource bundle is then used in a 3rd-party app.  When that 3rd-party app presents it, the crash happens if the connection is left in.

**Prior research**

- The xib is not using a table.  Most questions had a problem where they were linking the incorrect properties to components of the table.
- The link between the IBOutlet and the property is valid.  It's simple.  I can remove and reconnect it, as described, to cause the crash.  Other questions were not making a valid connection.

Comment: Is there any reason the 3rd party app wouldn't be able to see the label in the xib?  The only thing I can think is that the label, for whatever reason, doesn't exist in the bundled nib.

Comment: Not shown in that screenshot is another label, which the 3rd-party app sees and processes correctly.  Is there a way for me to inspect the nib?  I know the XIB is XML, but is the NIB file readable?  I'll definitely check it if there's a way, it might indeed not be including the label for some reason.

Comment: The nib file is basically a compiled version of the xib.  Is there some way you could replace the nib with the xib, which would be compiled at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the source is, but here is how I fixed it.

1. Delete your derived data folder, completely.  You can access this by going to File > Project Settings > click the arrow next to the path on the same row as the "Advanced" button.
2. Delete your Build folder, in the case it's different from your derived data folder.  You can access this by going to File > Project Settings > Advanced > click the arrow next to the "Products:" label at the bottom.
3. Delete all references to your resource bundle, as well as the library with related code, in the 3rd-party app.
4. Delete all references that you may not be using (such as separate libraries/bundles for Debug-iphoneossimulator vs. Debug-iphoneos) with the same name.  I suspect that maybe such folders were being referenced in the project settings (header or library search paths).
5. Clean both the resource-bundle project and the 3rd-party app.
6. Shut down Xcode, restart your machine.
7. Open only your resource-bundle project and build the resource bundle with the connections.  Build your related-code library, as well.
8. Move these files to replace the now-deleted equivalents in the 3rd-party app.
9. Run the 3rd-party app.

My strongest suspicion is that it was referencing an old version of the resource bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Is your FileOwner is the same class (i.e. WelcomeController) in which the IBOutlet for UILabel (whyWontXCodeBehave) is declared? For checking this, click on FileOwner and then check the "Custom Class" in "Attribute Inspector".

Also try making the clean build.

Comment: Affirmative.  The name matches the viewcontroller "WelcomeController".